# Eager loading an association of a subtype while retrieving a common set with multiple subtypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

Here's what I have:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Text < Element; end

class Graphic < Element
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets
end

Element.includes(:assets).all
```

This gives me an `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'assets' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`.

Is there any way I can retrieve all `Element`s whilst eager loading the `:assets` of the `Graphic`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [eager loading association on a subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149850/eager-loading-association-on-a-subclass)