# Rails eager load association on STI subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base end

class ChildA < Parent
    has_many components
end

class ChildB < Parent
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base end
```

I want to load all instances of Parent and Child applying eager loading. If there are instances of Other associated to Child they should be loaded as well using eager loading.

Using **Parent.includes(:components)** gives me:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'components' 
was not found on ChildB; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Note that almost the same question was asked 7 years ago and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149850/eager-loading-association-on-a-subclass). But the solution is not optimal and I am looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: ChildB does not inherit from ChildA - and the association is defined in ChildA. This just plain won't work. Either you have made an error and should have defined it in `Parent` or you should use a module mixin instead of inheritance.

Comment: The hierarchy is correct. I can define `has_many components`in Parent but they belong to ChildA. How would the module mixlin look like?